# ASP.NET Core HttpClient receive correct data only after second request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient

Good day,
I'm trying to download simple xml document containing exchange rates from some bank API http call.

I'm trying to send usual HTTP GET request over HTTP Client in ASP.NET Core application. But found out strange behavior and I can't determine the reason of this.

My Startup.cs code to initialize HttpClient looks:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 ;
services.AddHttpClient<UcbClient>(client =>
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "SampleApp-UserAgent");
            }
        ).AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(policy => 
                 policy.WaitAndRetryAsync(
                        options.RetryCount, 
                        retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(10, 3))));
```

And UcbClient itself:

```
public class UcbClient
{
    private ILogger<UcbClient> _logger;
    private IOptions<UcbClientOptions> _options;
    private HttpClient _client;

    public UcbClient(ILogger<UcbClient> logger, IOptions<UcbClientOptions> options, HttpClient client)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _options = options;
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task GetExchangeRates()
    {
        var response = await _client.GetStringAsync("https://www.unicreditbank.cz/cs/exchange_rates_xml.exportxml.html");
        var response1 = await _client.GetStringAsync("https://www.unicreditbank.cz/cs/exchange_rates_xml.exportxml.html");
    }
}
```

Code was reduced to be more clear.

If I send similar request over Postman or open url directly in browser, I'm getting correct results (in example some part of xml):

```
<exchange_rates bank="UCB" base_currency="CZK" date="14.03.2019" version="1.0">
    <exchange_rate type="XML_RATE_TYPE_UCB_PURCHASE_VALUTA" valid_from="14.03.2019">
         <currency name="AUD" quota="1" rate="15.244"/>
            ....
    </exchange_rate>
    <exchange_rate type="XML_RATE_TYPE_UCB_SALE_VALUTA" valid_from="14.03.2019">
     <currency name="AUD" quota="1" rate="16.689"/>
            ....
```

But if I do the same thing over HttpClient (UcbClient.cs) the first request returns the wrong xml (looks like some kind of scheme):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE exchange_rates SYSTEM "https://www.unicreditbank.cz/etc/designs/cee2020-pws-cz/xml/exchange_rates.dtd">
    <exchange_rates bank="UCB" base_currency="CZK" date="" version="1.0">
        <exchange_rate type="XML_RATE_TYPE_UCB_PURCHASE_VALUTA"/>
        <exchange_rate type="XML_RATE_TYPE_UCB_SALE_VALUTA"/>
        <exchange_rate type="XML_RATE_TYPE_UCB_MIDDLE_VALUTA"/>
        <exchange_rate type="XML_RATE_TYPE_CNB"/>
        <exchange_rate type="XML_RATE_TYPE_UCB_PURCHASE_DEVIZA"/>
        <exchange_rate type="XML_RATE_TYPE_UCB_SALE_DEVIZA"/>
        <exchange_rate type="XML_RATE_TYPE_UCB_MIDDLE_DEVIZA"/>
    </exchange_rates>
```

but if I'm sending the second request:

```
var response1 = await _client.GetStringAsync("https://www.unicreditbank.cz/cs/exchange_rates_xml.exportxml.html");
```

I'm receiving correct results. And I can't realize the reason of this. What did I miss?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey! I don't think it will actually solve your problem, but have you tried changing the User-Agent header you send on the requests made by your UcbClient?

Comment: This is also happening when you just open the URL you're using on a browser, it's not a problem of your code itself.

Comment: Hi @GabrielLima, I tried it alredy, it doesn't help at all.

Comment: @ALFA thanks, I haven't realized that it happens in browser also, probably because the page was opened already. Now I opened it on anonymous window and able to reproduce this. If I understand right it's some problem on API side, is it?.